# VB.NET - Serial Key Generating (Encryption, Hashing, Encoding?) Algorithm

Tags: licensing, vb.net, strings, encryption, text-encoding

I am trying to create a basic licensing system where I take a unique ID from the client computer, and I get this Hexadecimal string (hyphens removed e.g. "84-18-CE-...."):

> "8418CFEE73FA22E6AB0760C73A496497C6C347DA88A9F63B95FE1E1D6A350AA1D7D3A9EE870795AECC3C109AA8B4A78C"

It's only encoded into this format to make the ID longer.

Basically what I've been trying to do (without success), is to create some routine that can transform this string into a 25-character long (minus the dashes) string like the one below:

**`"H8G02-J8293-L02O9-S920Q-F8D9X"`**

*(An alpha-numeric key with numbers or letters in no particular pattern, preferably letter,number, letter or vice versa)*

I just can't figure out how I could then validate this key, so that I could extract the untransformed Hex string we began with.

- Note that the original Hex string will not always be the same length. Also, a routine that will convert ANY string into such a format (alpha-numeric, caps-only) will be acceptable.
- I just realized that perhaps this isn't possible (to shorten the string down to 25 characters, and still retain the information (silly, I know). I will now accept anything that will allow me to create a 25-character OR LONGER string, from which I can select 25 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the hexadecimal number to [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36).  Example [here](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/EN/units-converter/numbers/4-39/hexadecimal-base-36/).

According to that page, Your input yields

> 1DWCLWKQZK16WMKIIEYVLLXA9E4OQ64P80KDOH4ALCYRCYCTKRUHQRXTM6HLDEV78E6APXQV1JG

in base 36.

[Here is a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398465/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-md5-hash-into-a-string-36-chars) that has an arbitrary base conversion function in c# (alas, couldn't get the online converter to properly convert it to VB).  You can see it in action here: http://ideone.com/nDun6s

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! Could you please include an example piece of code that would allow me to do this (or at least a namespace/class to look for)?

Comment: C++ :S. Could you include a simple example in VB.NET? And is it possible to define the possible characters (map then out perhaps?) so I could exclude "O", like you were saying?

Comment: It will take me a few minutes to knock something together.

Comment: I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Well, it's not VB.NET, but there you go.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it worked, except I'm getting "8OZ000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B1PXBE4K0XIRU21JK9G47HLWV0NPL7RJ4YYLCLBKIG" as a result. How come??

Comment: Did you see the IDEONE link?  http://ideone.com/nDun6s ... Look at the output at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Exactly! I converted the exact code into VB.NET and that's what I get..what could be wrong?

Comment: Don't know.  That's where your troubleshooting skills come in.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I marked is as the chosen answer. :)